Are there duplo bricks 1x4x1 and 1x2x1?
My kids like to build buildings and play with them, and for some reason they prefer the Duplo size to LEGO. I would like to give them less squatty looking walls, and am wondering if they have 1x4 and 1x2 bricks available in the Duplo size. Their grandma has some like this, and they get excited about it.

While 1xN bricks aren't exactly available, keep in mind that regular Lego bricks are fully compatible at exactly half the scale. So a 1 brick thick Duplo-scale wall can be built out of 2xN Lego bricks

There's already an answer that the thinnest & smallest Duplo block is 1x2x2 but I want to add that other brands might have the sizes you want. My childhood Duplo collection (early 2000's) had some Tyco blocks that were 1x4x1, and some Tandem blocks that were 1x4x(1/2ish). Other brands could be harder to find though - you probably can't buy individual pieces of those brand's bricks like you can with Duplo on Bricklink.com.

Bricklink has got DUPLO bricks category. Based on this I can only see Duplo, Brick 1 x 2 x 2 being available in 1 stud thickness.

Or Duplo, Brick 1 x 4 x 2 with 2 Top Cutouts, which has fewer studs on top. Not as good to be on the bottom, but should be fine on top of the wall to lock together three bricks mentioned above.


Alex's answer is correct, 1x2x2 or 2x2x1 are the "smallest Duplo pieces available". I just wanted to add why there are no "1x2x1" or "similar small" pieces. This is a deliberate design choice to create pieces that are "safe to use for all age groups".
Many toys (4 to older) have a warning label saying, "Warning: Contains small parts, not suitable for children aged 0-3 due to choking hazard". The US definition for small parts is that they fit into a cylinder that measures 2.5 inches (6.35 cm) long and 1.25 inches (3.17 cm) in diameter, the EU definition is probably quite similar.
Duplo pieces are meant to be suitable for children of all ages, so they avoid any pieces so small that they might cause any choking risks.
